# Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy (default-cli)

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I have my spring boot app deploy into app engine as mentioned:

> mvn clean package appengine:deploy

But some time i get the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project dispatcher-api: App Engine application
>   deployment failed:
>   com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException:
>   com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
>   -> [Help 1]

Not sure what is happening, as the log itself is not much clear. Can any one help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the tool that you are using to deploy your App Engine is deprecated on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp), you might wanna stop using this tool to deploy your application as you may run into more trouble in the future, and start using the Cloud SDK.

Comment: I am sure if it the correct answer but thanks for answering. Appreciated that.